# Python, cantidad de dias ingresando año y meses

Tags: python

quisiera ayuda con el siguiente código, tenia que resolver un ejercicio en el que toma como dato de ingreso un año determinado, y el programa debía responderme con True o False si el año era bisiesto o no, respectivamente, y escribí lo siguiente:

```
def isYearLeap(year):
    if year % 4 != 0:
        return False
    elif year % 100 != 0:
        return True
    elif year % 400 != 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

yr = int(input("Ingresa un año para saber si es bisiesto: "))

while True: 
    if yr != 0:
        print(isYearLeap(yr))
        yr = int(input("Ingresa un año para saber si es bisiesto: "))
    else:
        break
```

Ahora debo escribir otro código en el que ingreso el año, y el mes, y el programa debería responderme cuantos días contiene el mes del año ingresado, y con ayuda del curso solo pude llegar hasta aqui:

```
def isYearLeap(year):
    if year % 4 != 0:
        return False
    elif year % 100 != 0:
        return True
    elif year % 400 != 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def daysInMonth(year, month):
    monthDays = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    if isYearLeap(year) and month == 2:
        return 29
    return monthDays[month - 1]
```

...pero no se como continuar. El programa debería tomar 2 datos de ingreso (el año y el mes) y como datos de salida regresar la cantidad de días pero no se como hacerlo y les agradecería mucho si me ayudan un poco. Desde ya muchas gracias. Saludos

**EDICION**

Cuando intento agregar el siguiente segmento if-break (para que si se ingresara 0 en el mes Y(and) 0 en el año el codigo deje de pedir los datos y finalice), el código finaliza *sin importar que datos ingrese*.

```
while True:
    mo = int(input("Ingrese el mes: "))
    yr = int(input("Ingrese al año: "))
    if mo and yr == 0:
        break
    else:
        print ("El mes", mo, "del", yr, "contiene", daysInMonth(mo, yr), "dias.")
```

Comment: @FranciscoJavier si claro, pero no se como hacer que el programa tome 2 datos de entrada y los combine en una sola respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te falta nada, sólo pedir el mes y el año para luego obtener el número de días.

Este código mínimo muestra como pedir mes y año por consola, y como imprimir el resultado:

```
while True:
    mes = int(input("Ingrese mes:"))
    ano = int(input("Ingrese año:"))
    print(f"El mes {mes}/{ano} contiene {daysInMonth(ano, mes)}")
```

Con la función `input()` ingresas un texto desde teclado, el que convertimos a entero usando `int()`. Las validaciones quedan pendientes.

Luego usamos `print()` con *f-string* para producir la salida.

Un *f-string* es una cadena que contiene expresiones Python encerradas entre `{}`. Tienes que anteponer la letra "f" al string para lograr que esas expresiones sean calculadas y reemplazadas en el texto. Sin la "f", la cadena se imprime tal cual.

#### Demo

```
def isYearLeap(year):
    if year % 4 != 0:
        return False
    elif year % 100 != 0:
        return True
    elif year % 400 != 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def daysInMonth(year, month):
    monthDays = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    if isYearLeap(year) and month == 2:
        return 29
    return monthDays[month - 1]

while True:
    mes = int(input("Ingrese mes:"))
    ano = int(input("Ingrese año:"))
    print(f"El mes {mes}/{ano} contiene {daysInMonth(ano, mes)}")
```

produce:

```
Ingrese mes:01
Ingrese año:2000
El mes 1/2000 contiene 31
Ingrese mes:02
Ingrese año:2000
El mes 2/2000 contiene 29
Ingrese mes:02
Ingrese año:2001
El mes 2/2001 contiene 28
```

Comment: wow muchas gracias! me es realmente util, solo que en el curso aun no aprendimos a usar las f-strings, por lo que no se si sea correcto usarlo. Pero muchisimas gracias de verdad!

Comment: @FacundoZavaleta. Puedes reemplazar el f-string e ir imprimiendo cada cosa por separado.

Comment: perfecto hermano muchas gracias, el codigo me quedo asi:
`while True:
    mo = int(input("Ingrese el mes: "))
    yr = int(input("Ingrese al año: "))
    print ("El mes", mo, "del", yr, "contiene", daysInMonth(mo, yr), "dias.")`

solo que al ingresar el siguiente fragmento:
`while True:
    mo = int(input("Ingrese el mes: "))
    yr = int(input("Ingrese al año: "))
    if mo and yr == 0:
        break
    else:
        print ("El mes", mo, "del", yr, "contiene", daysInMonth(mo, yr), "dias.")`

El codigo termina su ejecucion , no importa que valores ingrese

Comment: oh rayos no se como hacer que el codigo quede ordenado en el comentario :(

solo agregue el siguiente fragmento:
`if mo and yr == 0:
     break`

pero no importa que valor ingrese, el codigo termina su ejecucion sin devolver ningun resultado

Comment: Mejor edita tu pregunta. Agrega un título que diga "Edición" y luego pones este nuevo contenido.

Comment: listo muchas gracias

Comment: Sonará riguroso, pero la función `daysInMonth()` será más eficiente si empezara así: `if month == 2 and isYearLeap(year):`. Si el mes != 2 (o sea 11/12 meses), Python no ejecuta `isYearLeap()` y salta al final del bloque. Después del bloque anterior, definir la lista `monthDays = [31, 28, 31, 30, ...]`. En este caso no le va a hacer ni cosquillas a la eficiencia de ejecución, pero es bueno acostumbrarse a estas prácticas por si toca trabajar sistemas que si demanden muchos recursos.

Comment: @aeportugal. Puedes editar la respuesta agregando tu alternativa. Para facilitar la comprensión, conservo tanto código original tanto como puedo.

Comment: @CandidMoe ya hice los cambios en la seccion EDICION, puedes decirme porque al añadir el break, el programa termina sin importar que datos ingrese? aunque no ingrese 0 como valores, el programa decide ejecutar el break de todas formas

Answer (score 0):

Puedes meter una variable en la lista, así que esa función la puedes reescribir así:

```
def daysInMonth(year, month):
    febDays = 29 if isYearLeap(year) else 28
    monthDays = [31, febDays, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    return monthDays[month - 1]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano!